# Poner un checkBox como "checked" mediante un HTMLHelper

Tags: html, asp.net, razor

mi pregunta es corta, en que parte debo agregar la propiedad de `checked` en mi `HTMLHelper`, ya que debo mostrarlo por defecto como seleccionado, busqué en la documentación de microsoft pero no encontre nada al respecto :(

así lo intente hacer, pero no funciono

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Estatus, new { htmlAttributes = new { @checked = "checked" } })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debido a que está asignando el valor del modelo (es un CheckBoxFor), debería establecer el valor de Estatus en true en el controlador antes de pasarlo a la vista.

Comment: y si solo lo pongo como CheckBox?

Comment: Tambien se puede asi: 
@Html.CheckBox("Estatus", true)

Comment: O supuestamente, aunque no lo ha probado: @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Estatus, htmlAttributes: new { @checked = true} )

Comment: la segunda fue la buena :D